# didEnterRegion & didDetermineState not being called when the app is not running while implementing Geofencing without iBeacon

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am trying to implement Geofencing with out iBeacon. The
`didStartMonitoringFor` is getting called, but
`didEnterRegion` & `didDetermineState` not being called when the app is not running.

I am calling the `requestState` in `didStartMonitoringFor`. So the `didDetermineState` is being called for the first time. But not getting called while location changes. Can some one help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please show the code where you set up your `CLLocationManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God ! I got the answer by myself.

I have been doing all declaration and delegate method implementation in Home screen classs. I changed all part to `AppDelegate` class. Also made some changes to properties for location manager as

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Also implemented both delegate methods

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion){
    manager.requestState(for: region)
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    if state == .inside
    {
            addNotification(region: region)
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
            addNotification(region: region)
    }
```

And it worked !

Comment: Hello Karan,

         i am implement this code for and test but its not working please check this code.